# SQL Statement Needed - results from a range but not within another range

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have two tables.

- A MEMBERS table that lists all of the details about a member and
- a second table that stores a historical record of all of the changes to each column

in the MEMBERS table. For example, if a member's status changed from Active to Frozen on June 1, the MEMBERCHANGES tables would have an entry stating that change.

I need to create a SQL Statement that lists all of the MEMBER records that are in a status of Freeze, who changed to the status in a date range but that there aren't any changes in a second date range.

For example, I need all member who changed to a status of FREEZE between Jan 1 and May 1 but who haven't had any changes to the status field from May 2 through Aug 31.

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode
    ,MEMBERS.fname
    ,MEMBERS.lname
    ,MEMBERTYPES.description
    ,MEMBERS.STATUS
    ,MEMBERS.email
    ,MEMBERS.datejoin
    ,MEMBERS.dateexpire
    ,MEMBERS.daterenewal
    ,MEMBERCHANGES.datechange
    ,MEMBERCHANGES.newvalue
FROM MEMBERS
INNER JOIN MEMBERCHANGES ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERCHANGES.memid
INNER JOIN MEMBERTYPES ON MEMBERS.mtypeid = MEMBERTYPES.mtypeid
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT MEMBERS.memid
        FROM MEMBERS AS MEM2
        INNER JOIN MEMBERCHANGES ON MEM2.memid = MEMBERCHANGES.memid
        INNER JOIN MEMBERTYPES ON MEM2.mtypeid = MEMBERTYPES.mtypeid
        WHERE (MEMBERCHANGES.columnname = 'status')
            AND (MEMBERCHANGES.newvalue = 'F')
            AND (
                MEMBERCHANGES.datechange BETWEEN '2015-05-02'
                    AND '2015-08-31'
                )
            AND (MEM2.STATUS = 'F')
        )
WHERE (MEMBERCHANGES.columnname = 'status')
    AND (
        MEMBERCHANGES.datechange BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
            AND '2015-05-01'
        )
    AND (MEMBERS.STATUS = 'F')
    AND (MEMBERCHANGES.newvalue = 'F')
```

Comment: Hello Patrick welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) For example Im sure if you can remove `MEMBERTYPES` because only is use for typedescription

Comment: So what is wrong with current query?

Comment: That subquery on the `MEMBERTYPES` join looks suspicious. You didn't explain anything about that. You may just need to move that to the `where` clause.

Comment: what is the difference between `newvalue` and `status` You should explain your schema. are both `F` freeze? or one mean `False`

Comment: @Juan I'm sure the changes table just listed the old and new values at the time the modification was recorded. `MEMBERCHANGES` is just historical.

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, that would be my guess too but OP should take the time to explain it. I hate make assumption and then answer the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your query with aliases and removed some things I think were redundant. Forgive me for changing to lowercase as well.

```
select ...
from
    MEMBERS m
    inner join MEMBERCHANGES on mc.memid = m.memid
    inner join MEMBERTYPES on mt.mtypeid = m.mtypeid
where
        /* current status is Freeze */
        m.STATUS = 'F'

        /* changed to Freeze between certain dates */
    and mc.columnname = 'status'
    and mc.datechange between '2015-01-01' and '2015-05-01'
    and mc.newvalue = 'F'

        /* and no changes between later dates */
    and not exist (
        select 1
        from MEMBERCHANGES mc2
        where
                mc2.memid = mc.memid
            and mc2.columnname = 'status'
            and mc2.datechange between '2015-05-02' and '2015-08-31'
            and mc2.newvalue = 'F'
    )
```

Since current date is well past August 31 I'm wondering if you'll have a problem checking against the current status which could have changed in the last month and a half. I trust that you know the data you're dealing with.

It's also certainly possible that the status could have changed to Freeze during the first window but later changed to something else during the same window. And then its current status could be Freeze because of a change between September 1 and present date. I don't know if you need to check for that kind of thing but this query may not guarantee anything about the member status at the end of May 1st.

Comment: I dont think you need `/* current status is Freeze */` the problem is changing status between some dates, not about current status. And you miss a `*` in second comment. And `exist` should be `mc2.memid = mc.memid`

Comment: As I wrote it I looked back to see that OP does want a current status of Freeze. I still have some hesitation to say this is the right query for the results OP needs.

Comment: Yes OP will have to give final answer but with the clean up will be easier to understand. and update to his need. You still need fix the `mc2.memid = mc.memid`

Comment: For OP maybe you dont need the last `and mc2.newvalue = 'F'` if by `2015-05-01` you already was freeze, any change on `status` after that will trigger that `exist`.